# How to create a dynamic django template container reference

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to do something seemingly trivial in a django template yet difficult to figure how to do.  Suppose I have a list **field_list** = ['a', 'b', 'c' ] and a container named **report_item**. In a template I want to do essentially this:

```
{% for fld_name in field_list %}
  <td>{{ report_item.{{fld_name}} }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I have verified the report_item.a, .b, .c are accessible (even if they aren't that should be ok). I have tried every possible combination of quoting, etc. and web search for solutions, read the docs N times yet continue  to get this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{fld_name' from 'field_list.{{fld_name'
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I was asked below how I am building my items_list:

```
context[ "items_list" ] = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```

and I have:

```
context[ "field_list" ] = [ 
        [ "Date Placed",                "date_placed" ],
        ...
    ]
```

and in the template I have:

```
{% for report_item in items_list %}
    {% for fld_hdr, fld_name in field_list %}
       {{ report_item.{{fld_name}} }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

As I said before, if I do:

```
{{ report_item.date_placed }}
```

it works fine.

Comment: You'll need a custom template filter for this.

Comment: example?  I don't see how a filter would help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to dynamically get an attribute from an object. For that in Python you use `getattr`, and the way to do this in a Python template is to write a filter that calls getattr on its argument.

```
@register.filter
def get_field(obj, arg):
    return getattr(obj, arg)
```

Now you can do `{{ report_item|get_field:fld_name }}`

Comment: Yep, that is what I needed and it works great.  For bonus points, how come {{ x.{{y}} }} does not work?  I will give you credit when the bounty is available, assuming someone come up with a non-filter solution.

Comment: my misunderstanding on when I could accept the answer (confused by "bounty" stuff.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just try {{ report_item.fld_name }}. Hope this helps.

Comment: No joy, {{ report_item.fld_name }} is rendered as "" (i.e., empty string, as expected.

Comment: sorry, the above comment submitted accidentally - see my added EDIT to my main post for how I am building report_item.